# How to specify offset_column in h2o.stackedEnsemble()

Tags: r, h2o

I am running *gbm* and *glm* with `offset_column` as base learners in **h2o**. My response variable is *binary* and the `offset_column` is a positive constant. Base learners worked. Here is the code:

```
train["offset"]<-train["log_hazard"] # offset column in the training set

my_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = x, y = y, training_frame = train,
                  fold_column = "fold_id",
                  keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                  offset_column = "offset",
                  seed = 1) 

my_glm <- h2o.glm(x = x, y = y, training_frame = train,
              fold_column = "fold_id",
              keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
              offset_column = "offset",
              seed = 1,family = "binomial")
```

Then I am passing the `offset_column` in `h2o.stackedEnsemble()` through `metalerner_params`. Here is the code:

```
stack_model <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = x,
                             y = y,
                             training_frame = train,
                             base_models = list(my_gbm, my_glm),
                             metalearner_params = list(offset_column = "offset"))
```

But I received the following error:

> ERRR on field: _offset_column: Offset column 'offset' not found in the training frame

The `offset_column` is in the training data. I am not sure why I am receiving this error message.

Then I tried running `h2o.stackedEnsemble()` without the `metalerner_params` option. Here is the code:

```
stack_model <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = x,
                               y = y,
                               training_frame = train,
                               base_models = list(my_gbm, my_glm))
```

and received the following warning message:

> Warning message:
>   In .h2o.startModelJob(algo, params, h2oRestApiVersion) :
>     Dropping bad and constant columns: [offset].

I am not sure whether it ran properly. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you carefully read [h2o docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html) for `h2o.stackedEnsemble` then you realize that h2o metalearner won't need offset parameter anymore as it will use cross-validated predicted values from base models to train:

```
my_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = x, y = y, training_frame = train, 
              fold_column = "fold_id",
              keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
              offset_column = "offset",
              seed = 1) 

my_glm <- h2o.glm(x = x, y = y, training_frame = train, 
              fold_column = "fold_id",
              keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
              offset_column = "offset",
              seed = 1,family = "binomial")

stack_model <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = x,
                               y = y,
                               training_frame = train,
                               base_models = list(my_gbm, my_glm))

h2o.performance(my_gbm, newdata = test)
h2o.performance(my_glm, newdata = test)
h2o.performance(stack_model, newdata = test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @topchef. I run the code you provided but I received a warning message. Please see the edited version of the question. I am not sure whether it ran properly.

Comment: @ssaha this appears as different issue not related to the original question. Try searching for answers and if can't find it then post as another question.

Comment: I agree with you @topchef, the warning message is not related to the original question. Thanks again.